# Is there any difference between these sets? $ C=\{x\in A| x\in B\}$ and $D=\{x \in A \wedge x \in B\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$C=\{x\in A| x\in B\}$ and $D=\{x \in A \wedge x \in B\}$ and $E=\{x\in B|x\in A\}$

I think that $D$ is not a set because it has not properties. And the set $E$ and $C$ are the same set because has the same elements.But they are mencioned in different ways. I mean $C$ is a set which elements belong $A$ and have the property that belong $B$. And $E$ is a set which elements belong $B$ and have the property that belong $A$.

As it is written $D$ cannot be a set since to be one there are 2 options, either it is indicated which are its elements or it is indicated to which set its elements belong so that they fulfill some property.

Comment: Why is it not specified in your notation that $x$ belongs to a set?

Comment: It's not enough to use curly braces for symbols to represents sets. There are certain rules that you must follow and as [Sassatelli alludes to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4470174/is-there-any-difference-between-these-sets-c-x-in-a-x-in-b-and-d-x#comment9369197_4470174), "$\{x\in A\land x\in B\}$" doesn't follow the rules.

Answer (score -3):

They are all the same, the difference is only in the emphasis: $C$ is viewed as a subset of $A$, and $E$ is viewed as a subset of $B$.

There is a flaw in the definition of $D$, it should rather say $\{x: x\in A\ \wedge x\in B\}$.